# How to check the repeatable variables in a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm working on this Prolog question where I have to design a program that creates a grid of wizard hats of 4 different colours (blue, red, green, and yellow) where each hat has one of 4 different letters (w, x, y, and z). The hats have to be arranged in such a way that no row or column has two hats with the same colour or hats with the same letter in them.

I have to write a predicate validRow that is true if a row is valid, i.e., if no two hats have the same color or the same letter.

ex:

```
?- validRow([(1, 1, red, w), (1, 2, green, x), (1, 3, yellow, y), (1, 4, blue, z)]).
true.
```

This is my code so far

```
validRow([(R,C1,Colour1,Letter1), (R,C2,Colour2,Letter2),(R,C3,Colour3,Letter3), (R,C4,Colour4,Letter4)]) :-
    isValid([Colour1,Colour2,Colour3,Colour4], [Letter1,Letter2,Letter3,Letter4]).

isValid([HC|TC],[HL|TL]) :- 
    not(member(HC,TC)),
    not(member(HL,TL)),
    isValid(TC,TL).
```

This doesn't give me the correct answer. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Recursion requires a base case; you have not specified one for `isValid`.

Comment: @user7630822 is `isValid([], []).` true based upon your definition of `isValid`?